# Циклический остаток от деления в JAVA?

Tags: java, математика, mod

Мне нужно получить данные в диапазоне 0 до 5. Если аргумент выходит за рамки то мне нужно циклически продолжить считать с другой стороны диапазона.

Т.е.
При -1 ответ 5 (т.к. -1 % 6 = 5). 
В питоне подобная функциональность доступна.

Java: -1 % 6 = -1

Есть подобный функционал в Java или надо программировать свою функцию? Функция будет оспользоваться ОЧЕНЬ часто, было бы хорошо, чтобы она была эффективной.
Я написал функцию, но подозреваю что можно сделать намного проще (идеи?) :

```
private int cycleMod (int number, int mod){
    while (number < 0){
        number+= mod;
    }
    return number % mod;
}
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Насколько глубоко уходят отрицательные числа? Возможно поможет преобразовать в `(6*6*6 -1)%6` нечто такое, или... можно ещё как-то математически преобразовать.

Comment: не очень понял, почему `-1%6=5`?

Comment: nick не совсем понял что ты имеешь ввиду. Но по идее в моем случае отрицательные числа будут очень мелкими. |number| < 6

Comment: Не знаю как правильно математически использовать остаток, но гугл тоже выдает такой ответ   "-1 modulo 6 = 5"

Comment: в моем случае можно даже обойтись   number < 0 ? number + mod : number % mod

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Всё просто - используйте `Math.floorMod`:

```
System.out.println(Math.floorMod(-1, 6));
```

Результат:

```
5
```